# How to add class to div if background image equals a particular image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a div (vc_gitem-animated-block) if the background is a certain image. Basically, if my div has a certain image (vc_gitem_image.png) for the background, I want to hide the parent div.

If other divs have a different background for example (blog-fpo.png), I need the parent div to not have the class added, as well as don't hide it's parent.

I have this code in my page:

```
<style>
    .hide{
        display:none;
    }
    .show{
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<div class="vc_gitem-animated-block">
<div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/blog-fpo.jpg') !important;">
    <a href="http://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/join-savage-at-conscious-capitalism-2017-%c2%89uo-pitfalls-on-the-path-to-purpose-presentation/" title="Join Savage at Conscious Capitalism 2017 – “Pitfalls on the Path to Purpose” Presentation" class="vc_gitem-link vc-zone-link"></a>
    <img src="https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/blog-fpo.jpg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt="">
<div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>


<div class="vc_gitem-animated-block">
<div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png') !important;">
    <a href="http://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/celebrating-client-work-savage-brands-honored-with-iabc-bronze-quill-awards-2/" title="Celebrating Client Work! Savage Brands Honored with IABC Bronze Quill Awards" class="vc_gitem-link vc-zone-link"></a>
    <img src="https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt="">
    <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
 jQuery(function(){ /* to make sure the script runs after page load */

 if (jQuery('.vc_gitem-zone.vc_gitem-zone-a.vc_gitem-is-link').css('background-image') === 'url(https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png) !important;') {

 jQuery(this).find('.vc_gitem-animated-block').addClass('hide');

 }

 });//END $function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should add class to div (vc_gitem-animated-block) at the same time it hide the parent div.

```
$(function() {
  var list = $('.vc_gitem-animated-block > div');
  $(list).each( function () {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
    var ck ='url("https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/vc_gitem_image.png")';
    if(bg === ck) {
      $(this).parent().closest('div').addClass('hide');
    } else {    
      $(this).parent().closest('div').addClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/3jwavz9a/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are other divs on the page that will also have a parent called "vc_gitem-animated-block". Will this only add the class to the ones that have that specific background? I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Yeah, this code hides all my divs. I only need the ones with the specified background image to hide. Is there a way to have the other divs not hide?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle.Now you can see

Comment: Works great in my sample page. However in my WordPress site, it seems like it won't work because those divs are created using a post grid. I guess that element loads after the script is fired. See my page: https://savagebrands17.wpengine.com/savage-thoughts/